# Get information about donation

Tags: paypal

I have on my website paypal donation button.
How I can get all information from my paypal account about donations. Maybe exist API request or some XML feed.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check this one? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution:

Method: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/

NVP: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out PayPal IPN's

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/